# In Uno, can you play a Wild Draw 4 Card drawn as a penalty, if you have a card the same colour as the draw pile?

Tags: uno

E.g.
- Player 1 plays a Draw 2 Card.
- Player 2 picks up 2 cards, one of which is a Wild Draw 4 Card. He also draws another unplayable card. The draw pile is showing a yellow card. Player 2 has a yellow card in his hand (but he is not allowed to play these).

Can he play the Wild Draw 4 Card?

I say yes because he has no other playable cards.
My partner says no because he has a card in his hand that matches the colour of the draw pile.

What is the official rule?

Comment: I think you mean "discard pile" rather than "draw pile".

Answer (score 4):

**Official Rules**

"Official rules" do vary slightly from site to site, however all seem to agree (including [the rules on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uno_(card_game)#Official_rules)) that being on the receiving end of a Draw Two or Wild Draw Four forces the player to draw 2/4 cards **and** forfeit their turn, therefore Player 2 is not allowed to use either card, and play continues to the next player after Player 2.

Under the official rules you are only allowed to immediately play drawn cards when, on your turn you choose to draw a card, and the card you have drawn is playable.

**House rules**

Otherwise there is a common house rule regarding not ending your turn after receiving a Draw Two and/or Wild Draw Four.

If playing with this house rule Player 2 must play the yellow card - if they were to play the Wild Draw Four they could be challenged by Player 1, and end up drawing more cards as a penalty for playing a Wild Draw Four while they have a card in hand that matches the current colour.

Answer (score 0):

**NO**

You do not play *any* cards after having a Draw 2 (or Wild Draw 4) played on you.  You draw the cards and then it is the next player's turn. 
See the section on Special Cards in the [official rules](https://service.mattel.com/instruction_sheets/42001pr.pdf).

Comment: I agree, but your answer bring nothing new to the table. If you don't add a link or any source to the rules, your answer is the same as the previous answer.

Comment: Here's a link to the official rules: https://service.mattel.com/instruction_sheets/42001pr.pdf